# Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'setFocus' ('setFocus' was undefined)

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a form that when you put in a item number and click the enter button its supposed to look in the sql database and if it finds a match auto populate the item description field this worked in my dot net 6  blazor server app   version of the app but I am redoing the app as a dot net8 blazor server app

but now when I put in a cps item number and hit enter the page locks up and  I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Could not find 'setFocus' ('setFocus' was undefined).
    at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:734
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at l.findFunction (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:702)
    at b (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:5445)
    at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3238
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at y.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3201)
    at gn._invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:62841)
    at gn._processIncomingData (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:60316)
    at connection.onreceive (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:53957)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Surplus.Components.Pages.Form.HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e, Int32 index) in D:\Surplus dotnet8\Components\Pages\Form.razor:line 127
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit '1QuhfxUGR4yU6kOqMXrGLY2gy0C9NUoJwCO053QLvKQ'.
      Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'setFocus' ('setFocus' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'setFocus' ('setFocus' was undefined).
    at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:734
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at l.findFunction (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:702)
    at b (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:5445)
    at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3238
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at y.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3201)
    at gn._invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:62841)
    at gn._processIncomingData (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:60316)
    at connection.onreceive (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:53957)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at Surplus.Components.Pages.Form.HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e, Int32 index) in D:\Surplus dotnet8\Components\Pages\Form.razor:line 127
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

D:\Surplus dotnet8\bin\Debug\net8.0\Surplus.exe (process 42444) exited with code -1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

here is my form code:

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using System.Text.Json;
@using Blazored.LocalStorage;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService oLocalStore


<PageTitle>Surplus Asset Disposal Form</PageTitle>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="h3" style="display: block; text-align: center">Welcome Chris DeBrodie!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @foreach (var (inputData, index) in inputCardData.Select((data, index) => (data, index)))
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @if (index == 0)
                            {
                                <!-- Render the dropdown only for the first card -->
                                <RadzenDropDown TValue="string" ValueProperty="BuildingName" TextProperty="BuildingName" Data="@buildingLists" @bind-Value="inputData.BuildingName" AllowSelectAll="false" Placeholder="School Name" Style="width: 100%; text-align: center" @onkeydown="@(e => HandleKeyDown(e, index))" />
                            }

                            <RadzenCard Variant="Radzen.Variant.Filled">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <RadzenTextBox TextProperty="CPSNumber" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.CPSNumber" Placeholder="CPS Number" Style="width: 100%; text-align: left" @onkeydown="@(e => HandleKeyDown(e, index))" @onchange="@(value => OnAutoCompleteChange(value, index))" @oninput="() => AddNewCard(index)" AutoComplete="false" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <RadzenTextBox TextProperty="Description" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.Description" Placeholder="Item Description" Style="width: 100%" @onkeydown="@(e => HandleKeyDown(e, index))" @onchange="@(value => OnAutoCompleteChange(value, index))" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                </div>
                                <RadzenDropDown TValue="string" ValueProperty="ReasonDescription" TextProperty="ReasonDescription" Data="@reasons" @bind-Value="inputData.ReasonDescription" Placeholder="Reason For Surplus" Style="width: 100%" @onkeydown="@(e => HandleKeyDown(e, index))" />
                            </RadzenCard>
                        </div>
                    }



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Review" Click="FinalizeList"></RadzenButton>



@code {
    [Inject]
    protected Surplus.WASPOService WASPOService { get; set; }
    string KeyPressed = "";
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> surplusItemsNews;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> buildingLists;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reasons> reasons;




    // Create a class to hold form data
    public class FormData
    {
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
        public string SurplusSatus { get; set; }

    }





    // Inject the ILocalStorageService
    [Inject]
    private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }

    private productDtoVM product = new();


    // Create a list to store instances of the form data
    List<FormData> inputCardData;

    // Event handler for handling keydown event
    private async Task OnAutoCompleteChange(object value, int index)
    {
        var nextIndex = index + 1;
        if (nextIndex < inputCardData.Count)
        {
            // This selector might need adjustment based on your actual HTML structure
            var querySelector = $"input[rzinputtext]:nth-of-type({nextIndex + 1})";
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setFocus", querySelector);
        }
    }

    // Adjust the HandleKeyDown method
    // Adjust the HandleKeyDown method
    private async Task HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e, int index)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Enter")
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("event.preventDefault");
            var nextIndex = index + 1;
            if (nextIndex < inputCardData.Count)
            {
                // Assuming the next element is a text input. Adjust based on actual rendered elements.
                var querySelector = nextIndex == 0 ? "input[rzinputtext]" : $"input[rzinputtext]:nth-of-type({nextIndex + 1})";
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setFocus", querySelector);

                // Auto populate Description based on CPSNumber
                var cpsNumber = inputCardData[index].CPSNumber;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpsNumber))
                {
                    // Perform database lookup based on CPSNumber
                    var item = surplusItemsNews.FirstOrDefault(item => item.CPSNumber == cpsNumber);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        inputCardData[index].Description = item.Description;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inputCardData[index].Description = ""; // Clear Description if CPSNumber not found in database
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }





    // Constructor to initialize inputCardData
    public Form()
    {
        inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
        // Add a default instance to the list
        inputCardData.Add(new FormData());
    }










    private int cardIdCounter = 1;

    [Inject]
    protected SecurityService Security { get; set; } // Counter for the card ID

    // Event handler for adding a new card when a ReasonDescription is selected
    private void AddNewCard(int index)
    {
        // Check if the current card is the last one in the list
        if (index == inputCardData.Count - 1)
        {
            // Add a new FormData instance without copying the BuildingName property
            inputCardData.Add(new FormData
                {
                    CPSNumber = inputCardData[index].CPSNumber,
                    Description = inputCardData[index].Description,
                    ReasonDescription = inputCardData[index].ReasonDescription

                });

            cardIdCounter++; // Increase the ID counter
        }
    }


    // Function to save inputCardData to local storage
    private async Task SaveInputCardDataToLocalStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("inputCardData", inputCardData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving to local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // Function to load inputCardData from local storage
    private async Task LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            inputCardData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");
            // Initialize the list if it's null
            if (inputCardData == null)
            {
                inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
                //Initialize list with Default instance of FormData when nothing is stored in local storage
                FormData defaultFormData = new FormData();
                inputCardData.Add(defaultFormData);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        surplusItemsNews = await WASPOService.GetSurplusItemsNew();
        buildingLists = await WASPOService.GetBuildingList();
        reasons = await WASPOService.GetReasons();

        // Load inputCardData from local storage when the page initializes
        await LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage();
    }

    // Event handler for the "Finalize List" button
    private async Task FinalizeList()
    {
        // Save the input card data to local storage
        await SaveInputCardDataToLocalStorage();

        // Navigate to the summary page
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/summary");
    }

    public productDtoVM inputData = new productDtoVM();

    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

    public async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
    }
    public class productDtoVM
    {
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string reason { get; set; }
    }

    public void keydown(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        KeyPressed = "Key Pressed is " + args.Key;
        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("onFocus", "CPSNumber");
        }
    }

}
```

and my site.js code

```
// In your wwwroot/js/site.js file or an equivalent
function setFocus(selector) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (element) element.focus();
}



function printPage() {
    window.print();
}
function moveFocus() {
    var ele = document.activeElement;
    var tabIndex = ele.tabIndex;

    var inputs = document.getElementById("my-form").elements;

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].tabIndex > tabIndex) {
            inputs[i].focus();
            return;
        }
    }
}

window.onFocus = (id) => {
    var currInput = document.activeElement;
    if (currInput.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var currInput = document.activeElement;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i] == currInput) {
                var next = inputs[i + 1];
                if (next && next.focus) {
                    next.focus();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

window.saveAsFile = function (filename, content) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,' + content;
    link.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

i don't know what I am doing wrong any help would be amazing!!!! :)